# MATLAB - Undefined function 'affine2d' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

I would like to execute the following command in MATLAB R2012a:

```
tform = affine2d([0.92387953 -0.38268343 0; 0.38268343 0.92387953 0; 2 3 1]);
```

I keep getting the following error :

> Undefined function `'affine2d'` for input arguments of type `'double'`.

It seems to expect it to be a function while actually it is a class.

Can someone please help me with this error?

Comment: You need to have the `Image Processing Toolbox` to use that function because the code is correct. So I guess you don't have it. What do you get when you type `which affine2d` in the Command Window?

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'affine2d'. how do I go about installing Image Processing Toolbox?

Comment: Visit [this](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/index-b.html) page to get the details. You can get a trial version before purchasing it. Good luck!

Comment: @Benoit_11 - `affine2d` was released as of R2013a.  Even if the OP installs the toolbox, his/her version of MATLAB won't have it.  Sucks... but that's how they make money :( lol.

Answer (score 1):

`affine2d` was released as of MATLAB R2013a and is part of the Image Processing Toolbox.  See the release notes here for more details and look under the R2013a section: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/release-notes.html

Though you may have the Image Processing Toolbox, your version does not have `affine2d` as you are using R2012a.  The best equivalent is to use [`maketform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/maketform.html) and its ilk.  `maketform` was replaced with `affine2d` in R2013a as it is more robust and stable.

You either need to use `maketform` or upgrade your version of MATLAB to at least R2013a or higher.

Good luck!